# Simple php echo error

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
echo ("<h3 class='titulo_resultados'>No se han encontrado resultados.</h3>"); 
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

It shows:
No se han encontrado resultados."); ?>

Why??????

Comment: Why are you using PHP to `echo` a static string?

Comment: I'd guess php isn't activated and your whole php code is output. Check the html sources.

Comment: are you trying this in .html file?

Comment: Im building a dynamic structure with php, but starting with that line i get an error...

Comment: Can you post the output of the html source after you load the pagE?

Comment: PHP is likely not set up correctly - Add `<?php phpinfo(); die; ?>` to the top of your script, before `<html>`. What do you get?

Comment: No use paréntesis con 'echo', amigo

Comment: i tried this code on my pc and i got correct result. so nothing wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

My guesses here are either your webhost doesnt support php or the file has .html instead of .php. Also I wonder why u are using () after echo instead of:

```
echo "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you saved the file with .html extension. save the file again with .php extension. you will get the correct result.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
echo "<h3 class='titulo_resultados'>No se han encontrado resultados.</h3>"; 
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo` is a language construct and may or may not have parentheses. It doesn't matter.

Comment: The fact the OP sees the closing PHP tag (`?>`) suggests that PHP is not running at all.  If it were a simple syntax error, there would be (possibly) a PHP error and (definitely) no closing tag.